# Double Click Event on the items of the ListBox of a Userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, forms, listbox

I am trying to do a small "save as" interface on excel using vba, so that I can save some of the information that i have putted in my sheet in another sheet. I am almost done with it and it looks like this: [click here to see my Save As interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBKSj.png)

My problem is that I want to put an event on double clicking on one of the elements of my list, let's say SoCs2. On double click, I want the string "SoCs2" to appear in the textbox below.

I tried something like that:

```
Private Sub Listbox1_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

With Me.ListBox1
     For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
       If .Selected(i) Then
         Me.TextBox1.Value = .List(i, 0)
         Exit For
       End If
     Next
End With

End Sub
```

My ListBox is called ListBox1 and my TextBox is called TextBox1.
Unfortunately, this code doesn't work: when I double click on one of the items of my ListBox, it does absolutely nothing.
Can somebody help me with this issue ?

Comment: Please don't put your code in a snippet, as it can't run there is no need for it. Just format is as code by indenting with 4 spaces.

Comment: ok I changed that, any idea to solve my issue ?

Comment: Well first of all this only seams to be a small part of the code, at least the declarations are missing. So please provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also this code doesn't work isn't a propper question. What happens when you run it, what error message is shown. That should be a great way to start fixing your code, as you can google the error mesage and deduct the problem from that.

Comment: there is no error message, when I double click on an element of the list it just does nothing.

Comment: and yes, indeed, there is no declaration because there is no declaration needed. I just putted a ListBox and a TextBox in my UserForm, that's all

Comment: if I post this on stackoverflow today it is because I didn't found a solution to my issue on the internet

Answer (score 9):

The name of the Event Handler you are looking for is Listbox1_DblClick.  Try this:

```
Private Sub Listbox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(i) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = .List(i, 0)
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```