# Read first column's value of selected row in Listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I thought it could be useful for users doubleclicking on any entry in the ListBox (Name: Offene_PZ)
and getting information on another Userform. I want to achieve this by taking the value of the first column in the Listbox and paste it in a Textbox of another Form (Name: Packzettelinfo)

I got the Idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323704/double-click-event-on-the-items-of-the-listbox-of-a-userform-vba)

```
  With Me.Offene_PZ
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 'check for selected row
      If .Selected(i) Then
        With Packzettelinfo
        .show
        .PZ_ID.Value=      'paste the value to there
        End With
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End With

But now I


End Sub
```

Since I am still a noob in VBA (but still learning! Will start with VB / Java soon, eager to learn it) I would like to know if it is possible. (Sure it is?)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, wasn't so hard if you know how: [This was it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244582/10743243).

```
Private Sub Offene_PZ_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim i As Integer

  With Me.Offene_PZ
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(i) Then

        With Packzettelinfo
        .PZ_ID.Value = Offene_PZ.List(i, 1)
        .show

        End With
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End With
  Me.Hide

End Sub
```

So if I may explain: You loop through the Listbox entries, until the .selected row appears, then I take that row with `Offene_PZ.List(i, 1)` to return the value i need!